# R file garbled / corrupted and reloading encoding doesn't work

Tags: file, encoding

My R code file went garbled / corrupted overnight TAT. I tried reloading / reopening with all kinds of encoding in both Sublime and Rstudio but nothing worked. 
I think the information are still in it, just in a wrong form. So how can I fix it??
it look like this now.
(seems that I'm not qualified to post a pic, so here are some examples:
Œ(ð> „ÃŠ_=ÂŒ+"úÎ¤GÙÕbÿN¤    Ø4ÐºãžIE·±M§­ÑìäjY}×ò*,üê)
again... I really tried a lot of encodings.
[image]

Comment: the link is included.

Comment: Is this an R question or an text editor question?
It sucks that you may have lost your code :(. In the future, you should safeguard against this by using git (and github/ gitlab)

Comment: Though I commiserate with your plight, I agree with Khaynes that this is not related to [tag:r], as R is unlikely to be involved in corrupting or fixing the file. This to me could be one of so many things, including in no particular order: (1) drive failure; (2) file-encrypting malware; (3) the OS "glitched" hard; (4) the editor "glitched" hard. It doesn't look like typical compressed files (`.gz`, `.bz2`, `.xz`, `.zip`), I haven't checked against "standard" encryption headers. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks...0.0 I'll definitely start using git right away.